# How to SQL? Get values from this week sun to sat

Tags: mysql, sql

So here's the problem, i would like to display the data from a week prespective.

i could take today and take 7 days from it and make the query.
but i would like to do it from a normal week, from Sunday to Saturday.

So if i do the query today 26/feb/2017 i only should get the data from today Sunday.
and if i choose to view last week i should be able to see from feb 19 to 25.

how can i do this on sql?, i'm also working on c#

edit: So, i want to display information of the day/ the week / the month , so far

```
Consulta = "select nombre,SUM(horas) as totalHoras from SI_CanHoras Where dia='" + fecha + "' group by nombre  ";
```

works for today, for the month one is easy because i can get the month easly, but with the week i dont know a way to get the days for the previos or next weeks feb 26 to mar 4 - mar 5 to mar 11 would be the next , etc.

My only solution so far would be to write the weeks handly

```
String week1 = 26/02/2017 - 27/02/2017 - 28/02/2017
```

for every single week, since i don't want to look for the seven days before today

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: my best solution so far is to divide the year in weeks, so i would have like 45 weeks strings that i would call at the moment when i select which week i want to see

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you just want a list of dates? And how would you want to specify last week? Would a calendar table help?

Comment: Based on your edit it looks like this is not exclusively SQL, tag whatever language you are using as well. Also, please use prepared statements for security and reliability.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek

the Dayofweek function to get the actual day. It will return a number, 1-7. You could then add that to the number of days you wish to subtract (7 for a week) (-1, since Sunday is a 1) to get your start date. Now add 6 and you'll have an end date.

So, Today is Sunday February 26th. DAYOFWEEK() = 1. Now 7 + 1 -1 = 7. So subtract 7 days from the date. Now its February the 19th, last Sunday. Thats your start date. Now Add 6, its February the 25th, Saturday.

Comment: hi!, the problem with that is that it wont work tomorrow, because i always want to see from sunday to saturday, but you gave the idea, i can look for the dayoftheweek, do some validation, so i can see when was the last sunday and do the query from there

Comment: That's the idea @ErickReyes. I don't know exactly what you're looking for, but using this will get you what you want in pure SQL